# g++ cannot specify -c and -o with multiple files

Tags: makefile, g++

```
CC=g++
CFLAGS=-c -o
PROG=craps
LIBSRCS=craps.cpp craps_game.cpp craps_helper.cpp craps_io.cpp
LIBOBJS=$(patsubst %.cpp, %.o, $(LIBSRCS))
LIBCRAPS=craps
CXXFLAGS=-I./ -fpic
LDFLAGS=-L./

all: $(PROG)

$(PROG): $(LIBOBJS)
    $(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -l$(LIBCRAPS) -o $(PROG) $(PROG).o

$(LIBCRAPS): $(LIBOBJS)
    $(CC) -shared -o lib$(LIBCRAPS).so $(LIBOBJS)

$(LIBOBJS): $(LIBSRCS)
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) $(CFLAGS) $(LIBSRCS) $(PROG).cpp

.PHONY: clean
clean:
    rm -f *.o *.so $(PROG)
```

Why I am getting that error, and patsubst not showing rights output for compilation, really am confused

Answer (score 1):

`-c` and `-o` should not be in `CFLAGS`. Instead those should occur directly in the compiler command line where appropriate.

Also the `$(LIBOBJS)` target is not correct, you need a pattern rule there. The rule you have will expect a single compiler invocation to build all of the objects; but actually you need to invoke the compiler once per object.

Instead of `$(LIBOBJS): $(LIBSRCS)` etc. it could be:

```
%.o : %.cpp
    $(CC) $(CXXFLAGS) -c -o $@ $<
```

Comment: thanks, but why this line not executed after so that executable file generated ? `$(CC) $(LDFLAGS) -l$(LIBCRAPS) -o $(PROG) $(PROG).o`